# Google Map is not showing up

Tags: javascript, php, css, google-maps

I am working on this website http://dev5.99medialabtest2.com/carwash/ In the bottom, there is a section "Our Location". There is all code for the map, you can check it by inspect feature, but the map is not showing up on the front end.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parent container does not have any height, thats why you don´t see the map. 
Try to set the height of the div with the id of 'map' to some value and you will the see the map

```
#map {
 height: 200px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks jhen. Is it (this map) no mobile responsive? As it is not looking good on mobile.

Comment: It would be if you make the parent div responsive :) The div for the map itself does have a height of 100%, but the parent div does not have any height. So the child would expand to 100% of 0px which is 0px.

Ony approach could be to use media queries to make the parent div have different heights for each device

Comment: when you say parent div, are you talking about the div containing id="map" or its parent with class="google-map"? Please confirm.

Comment: Also, on many websites, I have seen it working without actually mentioning any height.

Comment: If you want to set the heigh on the div with the class google-map you have to give the div with the id 'map' a height of 100% aswell.

If you have seen a site where this is actually working, just look at the code to see what they did there. If you have a div with a height of 100%, you have to make sure either one parent div have a fixed height set or the div does expand in any other way (i.e. with padding and some text in it)

Comment: Thanks jhen for helping me out of this.

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing...after the welcome section, there are 4 services listed with the text appearing in the middle of the boxes. I achieved it using padding...can you help me with vertically centering them but without padding. There should be a way to do this.